# Shell script "for" loop syntax

Tags: unix, syntax, shell

I have gotten the following to work:

```
for i in {2..10}
do
    echo "output: $i"
done
```

It produces a bunch of lines of `output: 2`, `output: 3`, so on.

However, trying to run the following:

```
max=10
for i in {2..$max}
do
    echo "$i"
done
```

produces the following:

```
output: {2..10}
```

How can I get the compiler to realize it should treat $max as the other end of the array, and not part of a string?

Comment: what system and shell are you using? What kind of goofy system has sh or bash, but doesn't have seq, a coreutil?

Comment: FreeBSD doesn't.

Comment: Small style nit: I usually see the `do` and `then` keywords on the same line as `for` and `if`, respectively. E.g., `for i in {2..10}; do`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use a variable in for syntax in bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17787681/is-it-possible-to-use-a-variable-in-for-syntax-in-bash)

Comment: FreeBSD, at least 10, does have /usr/bin/seq.

Comment: @whatsisname, `seq` is not POSIX-standardized. Even if it exists, it's not guaranteed to have any particular behavior. There's a reason none of the patterns discussed in http://wooledge.org/~greybot/meta/counting (the relevant entry in the freenode #bash channel's factoid database) depend on it.

Answer (score 310, accepted):

Brace expansion, *{x..y}* is performed before other expansions, so you cannot use that for variable length sequences.

Instead, use the `seq 2 $max` method as [user *mob* stated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445452/shell-script-for-loop-syntax/1445471#1445471).

So, for your example it would be:

```
max=10
for i in `seq 2 $max`
do
    echo "$i"
done
```

Comment: There is no good reason to use an external command such as `seq` to count and increment numbers in the for loop, hence it is recommend that you avoid using `seq`.  This command is left for compatibility with old bash. The built-in commands are fast enough.
`for (( EXP1; EXP2; EXP3 )) ...`

Comment: @miller the `for (( ... ))` syntax isn't POSIX and that means for example that it won't work out of the box on things like Alpine Linux. `seq` does.

Comment: @Wernight Not just Alpine Linux; `#!/bin/sh` is Dash in Debian/Ubuntu.

Answer (score 96):

Try the arithmetic-expression version of `for`:

```
max=10
for (( i=2; i <= $max; ++i ))
do
    echo "$i"
done
```

This is available in most versions of bash, and should be Bourne shell (sh) compatible also.

Comment: @Flow: Hm, I just tried it on a couple of systems (Linux and BSD based) with #!/bin/sh and it worked fine. Invoked under bash and specifically under /bin/sh, still worked. Maybe the version of sh matters? Are you on some old Unix?

Comment: Very few systems have a dedicated `sh`, instead making it a link to other another shell. Ideally, such a shell invoked as `sh` would *only* support those features in the POSIX standard, but by default let some of their extra features through. The C-style for-loop is not a POSIX feature, but may be in `sh` mode by the actual shell.

Answer (score 37):

Step the loop manually:

```
i=0
max=10
while [ $i -lt $max ]
do
    echo "output: $i"
    true $(( i++ ))
done
```

If you don’t have to be totally POSIX, you can use the arithmetic *for* loop:

```
max=10
for (( i=0; i < max; i++ )); do echo "output: $i"; done
```

Or use *jot*(1) on BSD systems:

```
for i in $( jot 0 10 ); do echo "output: $i"; done
```

Comment: `true $(( i++ ))` doesn't work in all cases, so most portable would be `true $((i=i+1))`.

Comment: semi colon should not come in "for (( i=0; i < max; i++ ));"

Answer (score 19):

If the `seq` command available on your system:

```
for i in `seq 2 $max`
do
  echo "output: $i"
done
```

If not, then use poor man's `seq` with `perl`:

```
seq=`perl -e "\$,=' ';print 2..$max"`
for i in $seq
do
  echo "output: $i"
done
```

Watch those quote marks.

Answer (score 18):

We can iterate loop like as C programming.

```
#!/bin/bash
for ((i=1; i<=20; i=i+1))
do 
      echo $i
done
```

Answer (score 9):

There's more than one way to do it.

```
max=10
for i in `eval "echo {2..$max}"`
do
    echo "$i"
done
```

Comment: A security risk, since `eval` will evaluate *anything* you set `max` to. Consider `max="2}; echo ha; #"`, then replace `echo ha` with something more destructive.

Comment: (S)he set max to 10. No risk.

Answer (score 5):

This is a way:
Bash:

```
max=10
for i in $(bash -c "echo {2..${max}}"); do echo $i; done
```

The above Bash way will work for `ksh` and `zsh` too, when `bash -c` is replaced with `ksh -c` or `zsh -c` respectively.

Note: `for i in {2..${max}}; do echo $i; done` works in `zsh` and `ksh`.

Answer (score 3):

Well, as I didn't have the `seq` command installed on my system (Mac OS X v10.6.1 (Snow Leopard)), I ended up using a `while` loop instead:

```
max=5
i=1

while [ $max -gt $i ]
do
    (stuff)
done
```

**Shrugs** Whatever works.

Comment: seq is relatively new. I only found out about it a few months ago. But you *can* use a 'for' loop!! The disadvantage of a 'while' is that you have to remember to increment the counter somewhere inside the loop, or else loop downwards.

Answer (score 2):

Here it worked on Mac OS X.

It includes the example of a BSD date, how to increment and decrement the date also:

```
for ((i=28; i>=6 ; i--));
do
    dat=`date -v-${i}d -j "+%Y%m%d"` 
    echo $dat
done
```

Answer (score 2):

These all do `{1..8}` and should all be POSIX. They also will not break if you
put a conditional `continue` in the loop. The canonical way:

```
f=
while [ $((f+=1)) -le 8 ]
do
  echo $f
done
```

Another way:

```
g=
while
  g=${g}1
  [ ${#g} -le 8 ]
do
  echo ${#g}
done
```

and another:

```
set --
while
  set $* .
  [ ${#} -le 8 ]
do
  echo ${#}
done
```

Comment: Wonderful, I'm looking for a solution for busybox's ash, and your answer is perfect

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
max=10
for i in `eval echo {2..$max}`
do
    echo $i
done
```

You need the explicit 'eval' call to reevaluate the {} after variable substitution.