# Is it possible to use a variable in for syntax in bash?

Tags: bash, variables, syntax

I wonder If it is possible to write "`for i in {n..k}`" loop with a variable.

For example;

```
for i in {1..5}; do
    echo $i
done
```

This outputs

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

On the other hands

```
var=5
for i in {1..$var}; do
    echo $i
done
```

prints

```
{1..5}
```

How can I make second code run as same as first one?

p.s. I know there is lots of way to create a loop by using a variable but I wanted to ask specifically about this syntax.

Comment: The reason why it does not work is that bash performs brace expansions *before* variable expansion -- http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Expansions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not possible to use variables in the `{N..M}` syntax. Instead, what you can do is use  `seq`:

```
$ var=5
$ for i in $(seq 1 $var) ; do echo "$i"; done
1
2
3
4
5
```

Or...

```
$ start=3
$ end=8
$ for i in $(seq $start $end) ; do echo $i; done
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

Answer (score 2):

While `seq` is fine, it can cause problems if the value of `$var` is very large, as the entire list of values needs to be generated, which can cause problems if the resulting command line is too long. `bash` also has a C-style for loop which doesn't explicitly generate the list:

```
for ((i=1; i<=$var; i++)); do
    echo "$i"
done
```

(This applies to constant sequences as well, since `{1..10000000}` would also generate a very large list which could overflow the command line.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `eval` for this:

```
$ num=5
$ for i in $(eval echo {1..$num}); do echo $i; done
1
2
3
4
5
```

Please read drawbacks of [`eval`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) before using.