# Evaluate expression inside bash for loop

Tags: bash, shell, unix

If I do this, I get the result as expected.

```
for i in {125..129}; do echo $i; done
125
126
127
128
129
```

But when I do this? I get something weired.

```
for i in {$((1+(25-1)*500))..$((25*500))}; do echo $i; done

{12001..12500}
```

I wish to pass a variable inside the loop variables like `$((1+($j-1)*500))`

Comment: what does 1+(25-1)*500 equal ?

Comment: How does it relate to python?

Comment: @AstraBear 1+(25-1)*500 = 12001 :-P

Comment: @Linguist, yes, that is my point. See answer below. Hope that helps.

Comment: For the future, you should really try to describe the problem in the title rather than a generic "please help" title, so answerers have a better idea of whether they can help or not.

Comment: Please check the edited question. I have better explain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bash's brace expansion has limitations.  What you want is `seq`:

```
for i in $( seq $((1+(25-1)*500)) $((25*500)) ); do echo $i; done
```

The above will loop over all numbers from 12001 to 12500.

#### Discussion

`seq` is similar to bash's braces:

```
$ echo {2..4}
2 3 4
$ echo $(seq 2 4)
2 3 4
```

The key advantage of `seq` is that its arguments can include not just arithmetic expressions, as shown above, but also shell variables:

```
$ x=4; echo $(seq $((x-2)) $x)
2 3 4
```

By contrast, the brace notation will accept neither.

`seq` is a GNU utility and is available on all linux systems as well as recent versions of OSX.  Older BSD systems can use a similar utility called `jot`.

Answer (score 1):

Brace expansion is the very first expansion that occurs, before parameter, variable, and arithmetic expansion.  Brace expansion with `..` only occurs if the values before and after the `..` are integers or single characters.  Since the arithmetic expansion in your example has not yet occurred, they aren't single characters or integers, so no brace expansion occurs.

You can force reexpansion to occur after arithmetic expansion with `eval`:

```
for i in $(eval echo {$((1+(25-1)*500))..$((25*500))}); do echo $i;
```

Answer (score 1):

You query is very similar to :
[shell script "for" loop syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445452/shell-script-for-loop-syntax)

brace expansion, {x..y} is performed before other expansions, so you cannot use that for variable length sequences.

Instead try

for i in `seq $((1+(25-1)*500)) $((25*500))`; do echo $i; done

Answer (score 0):

It is just echoing the text which is exactly as it says:

{12001..12500}

That is "{"+12001+"..."+12500+"}"

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this with a for loop.  The {..} notation is not that flexible:

```
i=$((1+(25-1)*500)); while test $i -le $((25*500)); do echo $((i++)); done
```

Comment: A for loop would work (see the duplicate question), but you can't use range notation. `for i in $(seq $((1+(25-1)*500)) $((25*500))); do echo $i; done`

Comment: You *can* use a for loop, but not with brace expansion like the op is trying to do.  The only trouble with `seq` is that it is neither portable nor standard.  This is merely an example to show an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for (( i= $((1+(25-1)*500)); i<=$((25*500)); i++ )); do echo $i; done
```

or this

```
for i in $(seq $(( 1+(25-1)*500 )) $(( 25*500 )) ); do echo $i; done
```