# Loop does not work normally in git action

Tags: bash, shell, sh

Loop does not work normally in git action.

My task.sh looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

range=100
number=$((RANDOM % range))

while [ "$i" -le "$number" ]; do
    echo "DATE: $1" >> date.txt
done
```

The result of the above code is:

```
./task.sh: 6: [: Illegal number:
```

The code below works fine.

```
echo "DATE: $1" >> date.txt
```

I tried the following, but it also gives an error.

```
#!/bin/bash

range=500
number=$((RANDOM % range))

for ((run=1; run <= number; run++)); do
    echo 'hello'
done
```

I'm curious how you can make a command like below work normally.

```
while (random(1-100)); do
     echo 'hello'
done
```

Best regards!

Comment: You  never defined `i` in the original code, so `bash` is trying to execute `[ "" -le "10" ]` or the like.

Comment: @chepner Not necessarily. By default, `i` would be valued at 0 (or empty). Incrementing `i` is enough to initialize it to 1, 2, and so on. It would be cleaner, yes, but it does actually work as is. (see my script in my answer)

Comment: @VonC `[ i -le "$number" ]` would default `i` to 0, but `[` never sees the string `i`, only the empty string resulting from the expansion.

Comment: @chepner No matter, it still works.

Comment: What do you mean by "works"? The loop never executes, because `[ "" -le anything ]` is immediately false due to the error.

Comment: @chepner Agreed. I have edited the answer to make that clearer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238959/discussion-between-vonc-and-chepner).

Comment: The `for` loop you tried looks fine; are you sure you are using `bash` to execute the script? Something like `sh task.sh` will ignore the `#!/bin/bash` and use whatever shell `sh` refers to, which in some Linux distributions is `dash`, not `bash`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work fine with:

```
while [[ "$i" -le "$number" ]]; do
      ^^                    ^^
```

This requires bash, but since your [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) is `#!/bin/bash`, your `t.sh` script will run with bash, no matter its '`.sh`' extension.

But in its current form, it would be an infinite loop.

You would need to add

```
i=$((i+1))
```

That would increment the `$i` variable, making `"$i" -le "$number"` work properly.

Initializing `i` to 0 is better/cleaner, but `[[ "" -le "$number" ]]` (on the first loop, still "works" (in that an empty string is consider "lower or equal" to an non-empty "`$number`" string, and remains in the loop)

---

That being said, the more correct form/usage for that script would be (using [arithmetic comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18668649/6309)):

```sh
#!/bin/bash

range=100
number=$((RANDOM % range))
i=0

while (( i <= number )); do
    echo "DATE: ${i}" >> date.txt
    i=$((i+1))
done
```

Or, using a c-style loop

```sh
#!/bin/bash

range=100
number=$((RANDOM % range))

for ((i = 0 ; i < number ; i++)); do
    echo "DATE: ${i}" >> date.txt
done
```

---

All this assumes `bash`, but as [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1445507/6309), since `for (( ... ))` syntax isn't POSIX, it would not work with Alpine Linux or other OS where `sh` links to [ash (Almquist shell) or Dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almquist_shell).

In that latter case:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

range=100
number=$((RANDOM % range))

for i in $(seq 0 $number); do
    echo "DATE: ${i}" >> date.txt
done
```

Comment: The `[[` syntax is a bash extension so would require running with bash. The infinite loop is definitely a problem as well. :-)

Comment: @torek `#!/bin/bash` on a Mac means... you are running with bash. Even if the extension is `.sh`.

Comment: `[[` isn't necessary, as long as you initialize `i` before (and modify it inside) the loop.

Comment: `[[ ... -le ... ]]` is something of an anti-pattern; either `[[ ... ]]` isn't available and you need to use `[ ... ]`, or it *is* available, which implies the much more readable `(( ... <= ... ))` is also available.

Comment: @VonC: good point, I didn't notice the `#!` line at all!

Comment: @chepner `[[ ]]` is not an anti-pattern, when you are using bash: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56762558/6309

Comment: @VonC I am referring specifically to its use in place of `(( ... ))`, which provides more traditional comparison operators for integers. `[[ ... ]]` is fine for string comparison and the various file operators.

Comment: @chepner arithmetic comparison, right. I have edited the answer to propose a more suitable version of the original script.

Comment: And finally, the C-style `for` loop would be preferable to a `while` loop. The example the OP gave looks fine; I suspect the script was somehow not being executed with `bash` in the first place.

Comment: @chepner It was executed with bash in the first place, at least according to its shebang, as commented above.

Comment: @VonC Assuming the OP didn't do something like `sh task.sh` to execute the script.

Comment: @chepner True. Just in case, I have added the non-bash version.

Comment: Please don't suggest `seq`. It's no more part of POSIX than `[[ ... ]]`, `((...))`, or `for ((...))`. It also has to generate the full range in advance, rather than simply incrementing a single value as needed.

Answer (score 2):

You have two separate problems:

1. You are running your script with `sh`, not `bash`
2. You are not assigning `i`

For the first one, see [Why does my Bash code fail when I run it with 'sh'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15179446/why-does-my-bash-code-fail-when-i-run-it-with-sh)

For the second, set `i=0` in your script before you try to compare `$i` as a number.

Comment: ... and remember to increment `i`, e.g., `i=$((i + 1)`.