# automate swipe action on android studio emulator

Tags: android, adb

Hey here is my code for swipe on adb.

```
adb shell input swipe 200 1600 1000 1600 1000
sleep 2
```

But I want to loop it and run continuously. I'm calling my .sh files on terminal like this:

```
sh ./auto_swipe.sh
```

This runs the script only 1 time. How can I run it continuously?

Answer (score 2):

Possibly write a loop in script as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1445507/6478047)

```
max=6
for i in `seq 2 $max`
do
adb shell input swipe 200 1600 1000 1600 1000
sleep 2
done
```

To generate random number between 800,1600 script is ,

```
X=800
Y=1600
RANGE=$((Y-X+1))
R=$(($(($RANDOM%$RANGE))+X))
echo "$R"
```

inspired from this [article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/random-shell-variable-in-linux-with-examples/)

Comment: Thanks this works like a charm. Also, is there a way to randomize the x and y locations for more complex swipe actions? I mean I want to randomy swipe from y=800,1600 ? @Manohar

Comment: @sonelektrikci added code for generating random number